# rfc5322: what are the line limits?

Tags: email, rfc5322

I'm trying to make sense of [rfc5322 Line Length Limits](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1.1)
 . Is the line limit 78 chars or 998 chars? Is one for the body and the other for the headers? I can't find anything to specify that.

`Each line of characters MUST be no more than 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding the CRLF.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that preferably, lines should ideally be no longer than 78 characters but lines must never be longer than 998 characters.

In other words, 998 is a hard limit while 78 is a soft limit.

Comment: Right... now I see one says "MUST" and the other "SHOULD".